# Batch file logging output

Tags: batch-file, logging

I have a batch file that will run and give either a successful or unsuccessful `echo` per line when ran. There will be either 1 or 0 successful lines in this batch. I want the successful line to be logged to the mentioned .txt file.

```
@echo off
Title Kiosk Account Autologin Password Changer
::Query the registry, CHANGE the password, and report back if successful or unsuccessful
::These Kiosk accounts and passwords are pulled from the ICT SharePoint for East and West depots respectively
::Copy the "@%SystemRoot%" line and edit "User" and "Password" for each account as needed
echo Logged time = %time% %date%>> KioskPassword.txt
echo Searching for the active Kiosk account . . .
@%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /V "DefaultUserName" 2>NUL | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /IRC:"^  *DefaultUserName  *REG_SZ  *K003566$" 1>NUL && %SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /V "DefaultPassword" /T "REG_SZ" /D "EMj88qmjTyzy" /F 1>NUL && echo Account K003566 password change successful <======================= Active Kiosk account || echo Account K003566 password change unsuccessful
@%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /V "DefaultUserName" 2>NUL | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /IRC:"^  *DefaultUserName  *REG_SZ  *K004167$" 1>NUL && %SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /V "DefaultPassword" /T "REG_SZ" /D "xxn8YRryvuEK" /F 1>NUL && echo Account K004167 password change successful <======================= Active Kiosk account || echo Account K004167 password change unsuccessful
```

This part `&& echo Account K003566 password change successful <======================= Active Kiosk account` is what I want logged if it is successful. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would just log successful changes, IMO, you should log unsuccessful ones, as well as non existent accounts.

This is an idea of how I might do that *(implementing a few ideas to also shorten the huge line, and remove some repetition)*:

```sh
@Rem Query the registry, change the password, and report to file.
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions
Title Kiosk Account Autologin Password Changer
Set "Reg=%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe"
Set "Key=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon"
Set "Val=DefaultUserName"
Set "FSt=%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe"
Set "DPs=DefaultPassword"
Rem Call the Change function with your User and Password combinations.
(   Rem Example:
    Rem Call :Change "User" "Password"
    Rem
    Call :Change "K003566" "EMj88qmjTyzy"
    Call :Change "K004167" "xxn8YRryvuEK"
    Rem The above two Kiosk accounts and passwords are pulled from the ICT SharePoint
    Rem  for East and West depots respectively.
) 1>>"%~dp0KioskPassword.txt" 2>NUL
GoTo :EOF

:Change
Echo Searching for the %~1 Kiosk account . . . 1>CON
Echo %DATE% %TIME%
%Reg% Query "%Key%" /V "%Val%" 2>NUL | %FSt% /IRC:"^  *%Val%  *REG_SZ  *%~1$" 1>NUL && (
    %Reg% Add "%Key%" /V "%DPs%" /T "REG_SZ" /D "%~2" /F 1>NUL && (
        Echo  Account %~1 password change successful.
    ) || Echo  Account %~1 password change unsuccessful.
) || Echo  Account %~1 not found.
Exit /B
```

As you can see from the `Searching…` line, any you want `Echo` to the console, you redirect to the `CON` device, otherwise it will be printed to `KioskPassword.txt`, (in the same location as the batch file itself).

*Please remember that this must be 'Run as administrator'.*

Comment: The way it is currently setup, when unsuccessful the batch just goes to the next line to query. The full file has 250 lines, one for each username, and I do not want to log to be filled with 249 failed lines every time it is ran. Also, if I can shorten it and remove the repetition that would be great, because right now every line is a carbon copy with only the user and password changing. I think a CSV would be the most efficient, but I do not yet know how to implement those.

Comment: What!!! Your question is about logging output, I've shown you how to do it in the code above and about using `1>CON` for the lines to exclude. Are you expecting me now to rewrite your entire task too? I've already reduced your repeated `reg query`/`reg add` conditional lines to simply supplying a name and password as arguments to a function/label. If you cannot be bothered copying those into the parenthesized `call` section, then you'll need to change that section to a `for /f` loop which reads the name and password information from a file, and passes those directly to the `:Change` function.

Comment: No, I am not expecting you to rewrite everything. I am grateful for the help you have provided, I have learned a lot. I was just telling the current state of my batch file and the things I need to do to improve it. This is all new to me and I am trying to learn as I go, accepting criticisms and feedback along the way.

Comment: What I was trying to tell you is that I have shown you in my answer, not only how to log the output, _(your question)_, but how to modularize it and minimize the amount of typed lines you need. What you're intending to do next is irrelevant to what you asked, and the answer I provided. Is there something about my answer which does not cover your logging issue?

Comment: I think I understand the script you have made. It assigns the parts of my current string to a variable, and uses the variables to add modularity and make the line shorter. What is the difference between using `con` and a pipe `|`?

Comment: Simply, redirecting sends the output to a device or file, where it stays, a pipe passes the output to the next command in the pipeline, _(if it accepts that input)_. Does [this page](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) help you out? There are a few 'DOS' devices, the main being `AUX` _(COM1)_, `CON` _(Console)_, `NUL` _(Null)_, and `PRN` _(LPT1)_. The `Call` commands are parenthesized with all StdOut output _(`1>`)_, being redirected  to your file, and internally any `1>CON` instance will send that to the console, which means that its gone before it can be redirected to the file.